# What does "set - $VARIABLE" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Recenly, i read [Learning the bash Shell, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do) in chapter 7 section "Reading user input". When i
See the code below,

```
echo 'Select a directory:'
done=false

while [ $done = false ]; do
        do=true
        num=1
        for direc in $DIR_STACK; do
                echo $num) $direc
                num=$((num+1))
        done
        echo -n 'directory? '
        read REPLY

        if [ $REPLY -lt $num ] && [ $REPLY -gt 0 ]; then
                set - $DIR_STACK

                #statements that manipulate the stack...

                break
        else
                echo 'invalid selection.'
        fi
done
```

What is the exact meaning of `set - $DIR_STACK`?

Comment: It depends on the command. I suggest reading the manual page for the command in question. For the `set` command you have to read [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) as it's an internal command.

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug, where they wanted to run `set -- $DIR_STACK`. Which is *itself* a really bad practice. (So is `for direc in $DIR_STACK` as a whole, for that matter).

Comment: ...which is to say, I **strongly** advise you find a better book. A good reference (written by people who care about good practices) won't be encouraging you to use string-splitting to generate iterables, especially not filenames.

Comment: A good reference also wouldn't be showing unquoted expansions and all-caps names for non-builtin variables (see [the relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), fourth paragraph, for guidelines on variable naming; all-caps names are used by environment variables that are special to the system, but setting a like-named shell variable will overwrite any such environment variable).

Comment: (It's common for typesetting tools to replace `--` with an emdash, so I wonder if that issue was inserted during the publishing process).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i'll take a look at it.  :)

Comment: Read first line on page 297.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will string-split and glob-expand the contents of `$DIR_STACK`, putting the first in `$1`, the second in `$2`, etc. It's not good practice -- well-written scripts don't rely on string splitting (see the advice at the very top of [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), and many of the bugs below are caused by failures to heed that advice).

It's more properly written with `--`, not `-`. This is defined by [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), entry #10:

> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `-` character.

---

The use of `set` to change the argument list (`$1`, `$2`, etc) is also [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/set.html), though (again) the standard specifies `--`, not `-`:

> The remaining arguments *[ed: after processing options]* shall be assigned in order to the positional parameters. The special parameter `#` shall be set to reflect the number of positional parameters. All positional parameters shall be unset before any new values are assigned.
>
> The special argument `--` immediately following the set command name can be used to delimit the arguments if the first argument begins with `+` or `-`, or to prevent inadvertent listing of all shell variables when there are no arguments. The command `set --` without argument shall unset all positional parameters and set the special parameter `#` to zero.